# UITextView correctly highlight words

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I'm trying to highlight a couple of words from textView with rounded rects. And it all seems good, except for the line breaks where I get unexpected behaviour.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    for range in backgroundRangeArray {
        self.layoutManager.enumerateEnclosingRects(forGlyphRange: range, withinSelectedGlyphRange: range, in: textContainer) { (rect, _) in
            var newRect = rect
            newRect.origin.y += self.spacing
            newRect.size.height -= self.spacing + 3

            let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: newRect, cornerRadius: 2)
            self.highlightedTextColor.setFill()
            bezierPath.fill()
            bezierPath.close()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
(note the unwanted space between *special characters*)

Comment: How are you calculating the ranges in `backgroundRangeArray`?

Comment: Shouldn't "Special characters" be highlighted, with the space ` `, instead of "special" and then "characters"?

Comment: @matt I would like to remove that highlighted whitespace after 'special'

Comment: @Carpsen90 backgroundRangeArray is just a simple NSRange array that is calculated from position of strings for highlighting. I'm afraid text could be longer and same words could repeat.

Comment: highlight `special` and `characters` separately then

Comment: @Carpsen90 I can't do that as text could be longer and contain dozens of words 'special' and 'characters'.

Comment: Well then it comes down to the way you are calculating the position of strings to be highlighted. Please include the way you are filling `backgroundRangeArray` in your question

Comment: You could iterate over your ranges and if for a given range the corresponding text contains spaces break that range into several sub-ranges to avoid space highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got it right, you have ranges of string that you want to be on the same line. If so, you can replace a regular space in these ranges with a `no-break space` like that

```
for range in backgroundRangeArray {
    text = text?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "\u{00a0}", options: .caseInsensitive, range: range)
}
```